# Redirecting log output of Jenkins Pipeline Docker Plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I run a Jenkins Pipeline Docker Plugin step

```
docker.image('the-image').inside {
  sh 'thing'
  doSomeComplexStep()
}
```

and I want to capture the output of the whole `inside` block to a log file instead of writing to the Jenkins log, is there any way to do that?

I read the sources of the jenkins pipeline docker plugin without finding anything obvious, but that doesn't mean there's no way.

Comment: Have you resolved your question?

I met the same problem.

Comment: Yep, by not using Jenkins anymore for this and so so many other reasons. Sorry I don't have a better answer.